# Prevent Form Submission if dynamic field is blank....Php / Jquery / Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dynamic

Hello friends i need your help,

As you can see in the below image i'm dynamically loading questions select box and questions answer options in drop-down list from mysql database based on asset title value. ( this is working fine )

But my main problem is i want user to select all question answers and then only run ajax function and insert database in mysql.

**NOTE :** Some assets have 1 question some have 3 and some assets have **No** questions thats why i didnt used below code.

if(assettitle && customquestion1 && customquestion2){
ajax etc*** **[If i use this code then i'll be facing problem on assets who dont have any question.]**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a counter into some data-attr on the assets and validate that before AJAX in one shot.

```
$('.assets-selected').on('change', function(){
   $(this).data( "selecteds", $(this).find('option').length);
});

function checkAssets(){
   $('.assets-selected').each(function(){
       if (typeof $(this).data('selecteds') == undefined ||  $(this).data('selecteds') < 1) {
            return false;
       } else {
            return true;
       }
   });
}

if(checkAssets()) {
            //submit the form to server
            $.ajax({
                url : '../pages/php_action/addnewlead/creatlead.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : form.serialize(),
                dataType : 'json',
                success:function(response) {


                    // remove the error 
                    $(".form-group").removeClass('has-error').removeClass('has-success');

                    if(response.success == true) {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');

                        // reset the form
                        $("#newleadform")[0].reset();
                        // reload page after 7 sec.
                        setInterval(function () {
                        location.reload(null, false);
                        }, 7000);

                    } else {
                        $(".messages").html('<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">'+
                          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>'+
                          '<strong> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span> </strong>'+response.messages+
                        '</div>');
                    }  // /else
                } // success  
            }); // ajax subit               
        } /// if
```

**Fetch Assets Questions & Ans from database (PHP) - Put the class I showed in my example**

Look you're calling all questions once. Do a checking before do that to avoid errors and other problems

```
<?php  
 //load_data.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
 $output = '';
 if(isset($_POST["assetid"]))  
 {  

  if($_POST["assetid"] != '')
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM customquestions WHERE assetid = '".$_POST["assetid"]."'";

  }  
  else
  {  
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM customquestions WHERE assetid = 'akash'";

  }
  $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
  $quesno = 1;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {  
      //poor and ugly way to do something to filter, the best solution is the questions have a table 1 to N, where the 1 table is cover, main information and the N the questions, so each index from your array will be filled only with the questions that db has stored else will bring nothing and you can validate better the frontend, besides provides more scalability.
        if ($row['colqa1'] == '' && $row['colqa2'] == '' && $row['colqa3'] == '' && $row['colqa4'] == '' && $row['colqa5'] == '' && $row['colqa5'] == '' && $row['colqa6'] == '' && $row['colqa7'] == '' && $row['colqa8'] == '' && $row['colqa9'] == '' && $row['colqa10'] == ''){
             continue;
            //don't show dropdown if you don't have questions!  
       }
       $output .= '<div class="col-sm-6">';
       $output .= '<div class="form-group">';
       $output .= '<label for="campaignname">'.$row["cqname"].'</label>';
       $output .= '<select name="cq'.$quesno.'" size="5" class="form-control assets-selected" required>';
       // $output .= '<div style="border:1px solid #ccc; padding:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">'.$row["product_name"].'</div>';
       // $output .= '<tr><td>'.$row["cqname"].'<br></td>';
       $output .= '<option value="" required>Select Custom Question Answer</option>
                   <option value="'.$row["cqa1"].'">'.$row["cqa1"].'</option>
                   <option value="'.$row["cqa2"].'">'.$row["cqa2"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa3"].'">'.$row["cqa3"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa4"].'">'.$row["cqa4"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa5"].'">'.$row["cqa5"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa6"].'">'.$row["cqa6"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa7"].'">'.$row["cqa7"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa8"].'">'.$row["cqa8"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa9"].'">'.$row["cqa9"].'</option>
                    <option value="'.$row["cqa10"].'">'.$row["cqa10"].'</option>
                   </select>';
       // $output .= '<tr><td colspan="10"><hr></td></tr>';
       $output .= '</div></div></div>';
       $quesno++;
  }  
  echo $output;
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this carlos. 

i have re updated my question for you...Please re-check

Comment: I don't understand what in my answer not fit to you, can clarify to me, plz?

Comment: Amazing.. i made changes in php file that is working, but still facing the issue in jquery

   $('.assettitle').on('change', function(){
      $(this).data( "cq1", $(this).find('option').length);
   });

   function checkAssets(){
      $('.assettitle').each(function(){
          if (typeof $(this).data('cq1') == undefined ||  $(this).data('cq1') < 1) {
               return false;
          } else {
               return true;
          }
      });
   }

Comment: What issue? Show me the error or be more specific, please

Comment: @AkashSethi Pay attention, you're puttin the cq1 as data name, is not very intuitive, other thing it's the option, you're taking all options, but you want the selected ones, so $(this).find('option:selected').length, check the data values on console if it's working and put some error here to allow me debug.

Comment: I'm so sorry @CarlosAlexandre i'm totally confused on this code... actually i'm a beginner and. learning all from internet only...

Comment: That part of my code is to count all options selected in your dropdowns and store in each one the total of them, where before ajax call I check if all dropdowns are ok (i.e. with some option checked), returning true of false to conditional that handles ajax execution if returns true. Be calm, take a deep breath and review your code.